# Why is java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(...) hanging?

Tags: java, mysql

I am attempting to get a connection to my University's MySQL DB but the connection is hanging.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectToDB {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                        String url = "jdbc:mysql://db.cs.myUniversity.com/dbName"; 
                        System.out.println("BEFORE"); 
                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"me", "password");
                        System.out.println("AFTER");
                        ...
```

This call: `time java ConnectToDB` prints (after I eventually kill it):

```
Copyright 2004, R.G.Baldwin
BEFORE
AFTER

real    3m9.343s
user    0m0.316s
sys     0m0.027s
```

I just downloaded MySQL Connector/J from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html).  I am not sure if that is part of the problem.  I followed the directions fairly precisely.

I can also connect to mysql on the command line like this:

```
$ mysql -u me -h db.cs.myUniversity.com -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 882328
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> use dbName;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SHOW tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_dbName  |
+-------------------+
| classics          | 
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Possible Problems:

- The Java code I wrote
- How I installed MySQL Connector/J
- Some kind of network problem blocking the connection

**Question:** What should I do to solve this problem?  Why is the `getConnection` call hanging?

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm)

Comment: I am an idiot.  I am voting to close.

Comment: No you're not.  You asked a good question and provided a lot of detail.  You were thinking the whole time.  Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes, especially if you've been staring at the problem for a long time.  Don't be so tough on yourself.  I've seen real eejits here, and I wouldn't count you among them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output you provide is not helpful.

I see BEFORE and AFTER being printed, so the connection was made.  The code doesn't show what those timings encompass, so I can't tell what they mean.

If you're suggesting that your code had to killed because the connection was never made, it's probably because your username, password, and client IP have not been GRANTed permissions that are needed.

Could be:

1. your university network; find a network engineer to ask about firewalls.
2. permission in the MySQL database; find the DBA and ask.
3. your code; you didn't post enough to tell.  Post the whole class.

What's up with that copyright?  I'd lose that.

This code works.  Modify it so the pertinent parameters match your problem.  (Mine uses MySQL 5.1.51 and a table named Party.)  When I run it on my local machine, I get a wall time of 641 ms.

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils
{
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList( "Foo", "Bar" );
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(driver);

        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0))
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        }
        else
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st)
    {
        try
        {
            if (st != null)
            {
                st.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)
                    {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters)
            {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException
    {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters)
            {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }

            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        finally
        {
            close(ps);
        }

        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha!  Wow, you are totally right!  I actually didn't end up killing that process (I was usually killing them after 1 minute).  That one actually finished properly (and did not hang indefinitely).  Stupid question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer.  Why not vote it up as well?