# Impala JDBC connector got stuck

Tags: java, jdbc, impala

I'm trying to connect to my Impala cluster. But It gets stuck (didn't stop running) and shows no error and no result.

Here is my code:

```
public class testJDBC {
static final String JDBC_IMPALA_URL = "jdbc:impala://192.168.70.14:21050;AuthMech=3;UID=root;PWD=P13Ak!ix;UseSa‌​sl=0;UseNativeQuery=1;LogLevel=6;LogPath=f:\\Users\\joaquin\\Desktop\\Libros\\logs-driver";
static final String JDBC_DRIVER_IMPALA ="com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(getDolarFromImpala("2016-12-26"));
}

public static double getDolarFromImpala(String date)  {
    double dolar = 0.0;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_IMPALA);
        String sql = "SELECT valor FROM asigra.dolar where date ='"+date+"'";
        System.out.println("start");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_IMPALA_URL);//,IMPALA_USER,IMPALA_PASSWORD);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            dolar = rs.getDouble("valor");                                          
        }

        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("end");

    }
    catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(dolar);
    return dolar;
}}
```

Because it didn't showed me any error I set the logging to DEBUG and here is the result:
ImpalaJDBC_diver.log

```
dic 28 11:54:49.861 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIDriver.getProperty(20): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIEnvironment.DSIEnvironment(com.cloudera.impala.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCDriver@300ffa5d): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCEnvironment.HiveJDBCEnvironment(com.cloudera.impala.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCDriver@300ffa5d): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCEnvironment.createConnection(): +++++ enter +++++
```

impala_connection_0.log

```
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.DSIConnection(com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCEnvironment@254989ff): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(101, Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: ImpalaJDBC]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(139, Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: User]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(22, Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: Impala]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(58, Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: `]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(66, Variant[type: TYPE_UINT16, value: -1]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(68, Variant[type: TYPE_UINT16, value: -1]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(76, Variant[type: TYPE_UINT16, value: -1]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(81, Variant[type: TYPE_UINT16, value: -1]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(83, Variant[type: TYPE_UINT16, value: -1]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.876 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.setProperty(80, Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: N]): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.908 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.registerWarningListener(com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SWarningListener@446cdf90): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.908 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.updateConnectionSettings(): +++++ enter +++++
dic 28 11:54:49.908 TRACE 1 com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.CommonCoreUtils.logConnectionFunctionEntrance({AuthMech=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 3], ConnSchema=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: NULL], DatabaseType=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: Impala], HiveServerType=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 2], Host=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 192.168.70.14], LogLevel=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 6], LogPath=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: f:\Users\joaquin\Desktop\Libros\logs-driver], Port=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 21050], PWD=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: P13Ak!ix], UID=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: root], UseNativeQuery=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 1], UseSa‌​sl=Variant[type: TYPE_WSTRING, value: 0]}, "Major Version: 2", "Minor Version: 5", "Hot Fix Version: 16", "Build Number: 1018", "java.vendor:Oracle Corporation", "java.version:1.8.0_45", "os.arch:amd64", "os.name:Windows 8", "os.version:6.2", "Runtime.totalMemory:126877696", "Runtime.maxMemory:1879048192", "Runtime.avaialableProcessors:4", URLClassLoader.getURLs(): /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/New_folder/test%20impala%20jdbc/bin/, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/ImpalaJDBC4.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/hive_metastore.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/hive_service.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/ql.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/TCLIServiceClient.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/libfb303-0.9.0.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/libthrift-0.9.0.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/log4j-1.2.14.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar, /F:/Users/joaquin/Documents/impala_jdbc_2.5.16.1018/2.5.16.1018/Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.16.1018/ImpalaJDBC4/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar): +++++ enter +++++
```

I don't undestand any of this stuff so I have no clue what the error could be.

Please help!

Regards,
Joaquín

Comment: Have you printed the result of the `dolar = rs.getDouble("valor");` in the `while` loop - what is it?

Comment: Yeah, I tested all the lines and is stuck in the `Connection`, never passes that line.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4059004/6081445

Comment: One mayor difference with that case is: when I terminate the program never prints anything bellow `Connection`, tried with every line.

Comment: Could you try the createConnection code from the given answer to the question above, so the connection does only get the necessary information

Comment: Now it gets stuck in `createConnection`